# Unable to download Apps on iPad after streaming for an hour

Tags: ipad

For the past 3 days, I have been unable to download any apps on my iPad. The Apple ID button in Settings is greyed out, and does nothing when clicked.

But, I can still download on my iPhone as before

Comment: What do you mean by the 'prints are not black'?

Comment: You steamed your iPad for an hour...? I sure hope that's a typo

Answer (score 1):

Frequently, odd behavior of an iOS devices is addressed simply by turning the device off, then on again.

Or if that does not work, a soft reset may be required. A soft reset involves pressing and holding both the power button (upper right edge) and the home button (bottom center front) simultaneously. Hold those buttons for a period long enough that you see the Apple logo appear on the screen. A soft reset does not typically result in data loss.